# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in .net core NLayer architecture

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, repository-pattern

i'm trying develop an api in .net core with NLayer architecture and Generic Repository.

when i tried get datas i see an error.

my error
**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Fenerbahce.Business.Abstract.IPlayerManager' while attempting to activate 'Fenerbahce.API.Controllers.PlayerController'.**

IPlayerManger:

```
public interface IPlayerManager
{
        Task<IEnumerable<Player>> GetAllPlayers();
        Task<Player> GetPlayerById(int id);
        Task<Player> CreatePlayer(Player player);
        Task UpdatePlayer(Player playerToBeUpdated,Player player);
        Task DeletePlayer(Player player);
}
```

PlayerManager

private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

```
public PlayerManager(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
public async Task<Player> CreatePlayer(Player player)
{
    await _unitOfWork.Players.AddAsync(player);
    await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
    return player;
}

public async Task DeletePlayer(Player player)
{
    _unitOfWork.Players.Remove(player);
    await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Player>> GetAllPlayers()
{
    return await _unitOfWork.Players.GetAllAsync();
}

public async Task<Player> GetPlayerById(int id)
{
    return await _unitOfWork.Players.GetByIdAsync(id);
}

public async Task UpdatePlayer(Player playerToBeUpdated, Player player)
{
    
    playerToBeUpdated.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
}
```

}

IUnitOfWork

```
  public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IBranchDal Branchs { get; }
        ICoachDal Coachs { get; }
        IPlayerDal Players {get;}
        ITeamDal Teams {get;}
        Task<int> CommitAsync();
    }
```

EfUnitOfWork.cs

```
public class EfUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly FBDbContext _context;
    private EfBranchDal _branchDal;
    private EfCoachDal _coachDal;
    private EfPlayerDal _playerDal;
    private EfTeamDal _teamDal;
   

    public EfUnitOfWork(FBDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public IBranchDal Branchs => _branchDal = _branchDal ?? new EfBranchDal(_context);

    public ICoachDal Coachs => _coachDal = _coachDal ?? new EfCoachDal(_context);

    public IPlayerDal Players => _playerDal = _playerDal ?? new EfPlayerDal(_context);

    public ITeamDal Teams => _teamDal = _teamDal ?? new EfTeamDal(_context);

    public async Task<int> CommitAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

     public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

PlayerController.cs

```
  public class PlayerController:ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IPlayerManager _playerManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper; 
    
        public PlayerController(IPlayerManager playerManager, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this._playerManager = playerManager;
            this._mapper = mapper;
       
        }

        [HttpGet] 
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PlayerDTO>>> ListAllPlayers()
        {
            var players = await _playerManager.GetAllPlayers();

            var playerResources = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Player>,
            IEnumerable<PlayerDTO>>(players);
            return Ok(playerResources);

        }
    }
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: It's telling you exactly what's wrong `Unable to resolve service for type 'Fenerbahce.Business.Abstract.IPlayerManager' while attempting to activate 'Fenerbahce.API.Controllers.PlayerController` - You need a type that implements the interface registered to your dependency injection framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the dependency injection container is missing. You can use the unity/ninject/autofac for this and you can learn how to use from google.

Also, HER ZAMAN HER YERDE..

Comment: yeah, i added transient to services and this working..

as you said bütün bu alemde en büyüksün fenerbahçe..